# How to add a sharpPDF into a Word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, ole, pdfsharp

I'm working on an application in asp.net / C# 3.5 / Winforms.

This application is rendering a PDF file and a Word file.

We use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word for word and sharpPDF for PDF.

Our client ask us to put the same thing that is in the PDF into the Word document.

How can I do such a thing easily whithout touch the existing code ?

Here is the kind of code I want to do

```
pdfDocument myPdf = new pdfDocument("Title", "Title");
// fill pdf

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application msWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
// fill word

msWord.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMarkId).Range = myPdf ;
```

Edit : An idea could be

1. create the pdf file
2. load the pdf into an Image
3. rendering in word the Image

Any idea about how to convert PDF into Image ?

Edit2 : I have find this function AddOLEObject

How can I linked my PDF which is in memory to that function ?

Comment: For my stuff we create the word doc, then use the MS plug-in to create the PDF: https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=f1fc413c-6d89-4f15-991b-63b07ba5f2e5&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the solution with AddOLEObject and creating a temporary pdf file :

```
string tempNameFilePdf = "C:\\temp\\temp" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".pdf";
pdfDocument pdfDocument = getPdf();

pdfDocument.createPDF(tempNameFilePdf);
object oBookMarkId = "Schema";

object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

object fileNameObject = tempNameFilePdf;
object classType = "AcroRd32.Document";
object oFalse = false;

wordDocument.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMarkId).Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(
             ref classType, ref fileNameObject, ref missing, ref missing,
             ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```